# Programming way to list shared library dependency on linux

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries, dependency-management

Is there any programming way (system call?) to list shared library dependency on Linux? Instead of using `ldd` ...

Comment: just a generic answer before a real one arrives: you can always check the source of the program (in this case `ldd`) to see what it does.

Answer (score 4):

```
readelf -Wa lib.so|grep NEEDED
```

Comment: readelf -d lib.so is much more efficient, as it doesn't need to decode *all* info. Also, this doesn't provide complete (transitive) list of dependencies that 'ldd' provides; only the direct ones.

Answer (score 1):

Gentoo Linux has an lddtree.sh
http://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-projects/pax-utils/lddtree.sh?revision=1.22&content-type=text%2Fplain

You may find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Set LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS environment variable to non-empty string and run your binary. Look at [this](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld.so) man page.

```
LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS
    (ELF only) If set to non-empty string, causes the program to list its dynamic library dependencies, as if run by ldd(1), instead of running normally.
```

Comment: What if I want to check the dependency of a shared library, not a binary? In this case, I cannot run the shared library ... Thanks.

Comment: You can run ld.so on shared library this way: /lib/ld-2.11.2.so --list /lib/libc.so.6

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple bash script I use myself on Fedora, it relies on find-requires of rpm package, you can look inside find-requires to find what tools it internally uses.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Use rpm to recursively list dependencies of all files in a directory
#
# Syntax:
#   lsdep path/to/directory
# Example:
#   lsdep /usr/src/kernels/`uname -r`/

find $1 -type f -exec sh -c 'res=`echo '{}' | /usr/lib/rpm/find-requires`; [ -n "$res" ] && (echo;echo file '{}'; echo $res)' \;
```